# Autolayout, retaining button spacing for larger screens

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a setup like this in the interface builder:

[image]

(iphone5 size). I want the buttons to stay in that layout if the screen size increases i.e widens (but the buttons stay the same size). If I pin the top two buttons to their respective container edges when the screen is larger they will be too far apart from each other. I have the bottom button increasing its size fine. How can I do this? I tried putting a transparent UIView between each button and the container edge, but couldn't get it working this way. Could someone give me a pointer on how to do this please? thanks!

Comment: you want to resize it but keep the space in between fixed?

Comment: I want the buttons to remain the same size but move when the screen size increases so the layout looks the same as above.

Comment: @Kex are you still looking for an answer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the width, height and y-constraints in place, to create the correct x-constraints you can try something along the lines of this:

1. check the `Horizontal Center in Container` option
2. choose your button and double click the newly created constraint `Align Center X to`
3. change the `Second Item` from `Center X` to `Trailing`
4. enter a `constant` value to offset the position

Do this for both buttons. The `constant` value of the second button should be the negative of the first one AND its `Second Item` should be `Leading`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Result**
This method will result in equal spacing on all size classes.
[image]
[image]

The only drawback is that the spacing is no dynamic. for that purpose you would need some placeholder view in between.

Comment: 1.) Do horizontal center for the button?

Comment: I am adding screenshots

Comment: hey! Sorry just taking a look now. I couldn't find where to do the first part. How do I get the horizontal center in container? I have no option for this in my button constraints.

Comment: There should be: click the button, on the left-most constraint thingy at the bottom there is / has to be the option to do so. my first screenshot clarifies where that option is supposed to be, maybe post a screenshot yourself if you can´t find it there

Comment: Hey sorry was away a few days. Managed to get this working. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would say there are two approaches you could take:

Assumption is buttons have constraints for width and height.

1) Use a transparent view which you center horizontally within its containing view. Then pin the left buttons trailing edge to the transparent view and the right buttons leading edge to the center. You have a choice as to how to define their vertical position.

or

2) Add a transparent container view to your main view and then move your two buttons inside this view. Pin the two buttons apart the desired width and then pin the other button edges to the containing view at size 0pts. Finally center the new containing view horizontally in the view. You will need to define the height of this container view from the top or bottom.

The second is probably easier to execute within storyboard.

Comment: I tried the second method but then the buttons wouldn't work. Do they have to me connected to the transparent view instead on the main view?